# Replace spaces with one dash and only allow Aphanumeric in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I'm trying to achieve this kind of result:

From `This  is a test` to `this-is-a-test`

But I'd like to implement these rules:

- Convert all spaces to dash.
- Only allow one space (dash) between each two words.
- Don't allow a dash a the beginning or end of the sentence.
- Only allow letters, numbers and `à ç _ è - é ù`.

For now I'm using this partial solution:

```
const str = "This is dope";
const result = str.trim().replace(/\s+/g, "-").toLowerCase();
console.log(result) // this-is-dope
```

But this doesn't solve the whole problem because it doesn't have all the rules I mentioned.

I appreciate any help in this matter!

EDIT: I'm using React, and I need to implement this solution in an input field as follow :

Using the solution from `mplungjan` :

```
// state to hold the typed value
const [text, setText] = useState("");

<input
  type="text"
  onChange={(e) => {
    setText(
      e.target.value
        .trim()
        .replace(/^-+|-+$/g, "")
        .replace(/[-\s]+/g, "-")
        .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-àç_èéù]/g, "")
        .toLowerCase()
    );
    // unable to type spaces or dashes at all so far
    console.log(text);
  }}
  value={text}
/>
```

Comment: Both examples work, what is the question? Is there a non working example? Do you want to check beforehand if these rules are valid, of correct them afterwards?

Comment: The example I provided is just a partial solution, it doesn't have all the rules I mentioned (I still can add multiple spaces/dashes between words, add dash at the beginning or end etc...)

Comment: So you want to sanitize the string?

Comment: Did you mean *any Unicode letter* when you mentioned *`à ç _ è - é ù`*?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I only need those characters, I updated my question.

Comment: I see, the *Don't allow a dash a the beginning or end of the sentence.* rule is not in sync with the live input validation requirement. You must allow leading/trailing hyphens to allow typing them at all.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your solution works partially, as you said I still can type dashes at the beginner/end, but can we at least convert spaces to dash while allowing only one space (dash) between each two words?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I guess your solution is good enough `.trim().replace(/[-\s]+/g, "-").replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9àç_èéù-]+/g, "") .toLowerCase(),` I can type dashes at the beginning & end it's not a big deal. But can we also allow typing space and right away it converts to a dash? Because for now I'm unable to type a space.

Comment: @Dwix Then try `value.replace(/[-\s]+/g, "-").replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9àç_èéù-]+/g, "").toLowerCase()`, without `trim()`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah I see, I forgot about the trim, Thank you!

Comment: It seems you can still disallow the initial `-`. I posted an answer with a React snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
function App() {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('');
  function toKebabCase({ target: { value } }) {
    setText( value.replace(/[-\s]+/g, "-").replace(/^-/, '').replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9àç_èéù-]+/g, "").toLowerCase() )
  }
  return  <div>
      Text: <input type='text' onChange={toKebabCase} value={text} />
  </div>
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

The `value.replace(/[-\s]+/g, "-").replace(/^-/, '').replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9àç_èéù-]+/g, "").toLowerCase()`  will

- replace one or more whitespace and/or hyphen chars with a single `-` (with `.replace(/[-\s]+/g, "-")`) and then
- remove the first `-` (with `.replace(/^-/, '')`)
- remove any chars other than ASCII letters, digits, `_`, `-`, `à`, `ç`, `è`, `é` and `ù` (with `.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9àç_èéù-]+/g, "")`)
- turn the result into lower case (with `.toLowerCase()`).

Comment: I ended up removing the first `-` using an if statment, but this is even better. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

```js
const str = "- This is0 dope $$ !";
const result = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^0-9a-z ]+/g,'').trim().replace(/\s+/g, '-');
console.log(result)
```